# Operaciones entre arreglos

Tags: c#

por favor si alguien me puede ayudar lo que pasa es que el problema que nos planteo el profesor, es el siguiente, un torneo de futbol con 17 equipos, los datos que nos dan son los nombres de los equipos, partidos ganados y puntos obtenidos, segun esto debemos calcular los partidos perdidos y partidos empatados y mostrarlos, pero no he podido llegar a una conclusion sobre como hacer la operacion entre los arreglos que nos dan, y ademas de esto el profe nos dijo que igualmente se podia realizar con matrices, si  alguien piensa que es mas eficientes con matrices, agradeceria que me dejara abajo la explicacion.

```
        string[] equipo = new string[17];
        int[] puntos = new int[17];
        int[] pjugados = new int[17];
        int[] pganados = new int[17];
        int[] p_perdidos = new int[17];
        int[] p_emptados = new int[17];
        equipo[0] = "La Tebaida F. C.";
        equipo[1] = "Valledupar";
        equipo[2] = "Universitario de Popayán";
        equipo[3] = "Unión Magdalena";
        equipo[4] = "Real Santander";
        equipo[5] = "Real Cartagena";
        equipo[6] = "Quindío";
        equipo[7] = "Pereira";
        equipo[8] = "Orsomarso SC";
        equipo[9] = "Llaneros FC";
        equipo[10] = "Leones";
        equipo[11] = "Fortaleza C.E.I.F";
        equipo[12] = "Cúcuta";
        equipo[13] = "Boyacá Chicó";
        equipo[14] = "Bogotá FC";
        equipo[15] = "Barranquilla F.C.";
        equipo[16] = "Atlético FC";
        pjugados[0] = 10;
        pjugados[1] = 12;
        pjugados[2] = 11;
        pjugados[3] = 11;
        pjugados[4] = 10;
        pjugados[5] = 11;
        pjugados[6] = 10;
        pjugados[7] = 11;
        pjugados[8] = 11;
        pjugados[9] = 11;
        pjugados[10] = 11;
        pjugados[11] = 11;
        pjugados[12] = 11;
        pjugados[13] = 11;
        pjugados[14] = 11;
        pjugados[15] = 11;
        pjugados[16] = 10;
        pganados[0] = 5;
        pganados[1] = 4;
        pganados[2] = 2;
        pganados[3] = 4;
        pganados[4] = 6;
        pganados[5] = 1;
        pganados[6] = 5;
        pganados[7] = 7;
        pganados[8] = 5;
        pganados[9] = 6;
        pganados[10] = 5;
        pganados[11] = 4;
        pganados[12] = 3;
        pganados[13] = 4;
        pganados[14] = 2;
        pganados[15] = 5;
        pganados[16] = 2;
        puntos[0] = 17;
        puntos[1] = 13;
        puntos[2] = 10;
        puntos[3] = 14;
        puntos[4] = 20;
        puntos[5] = 6;
        puntos[6] = 17;
        puntos[7] = 24;
        puntos[8] = 18;
        puntos[9] = 20;
        puntos[10] = 16;
        puntos[11] = 16;
        puntos[12] = 14;
        puntos[13] = 16;
        puntos[14] = 8;
        puntos[15] = 17;
        puntos[16] = 10;
```

Comment: Hola @PedroAndres, en la comunidad no lleva muy bien que alguien formule una petición para que se le haga su tarea. Si por el contrario, lo que deseas es que te podamos ayudar a solventar alguna duda, te sugiero que copies el código de lo que llevas efectuado e intentado y lo añadas a tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Yo creo que en este caso en particular en el que el OP no tiene una duda puntual sino que no sabe cómo formular el algoritmo, es difícil que muestre lo que ha intentado, además no está pidiendo que se lo hagan. Es posible orientarlo sin tener que dar el código del ejercicio completo resuelto.

Answer (score 4):

Asumiendo que se siguen éstos principios:

- **Una victoria da 3 puntos**.
- **Un empate da 1 punto**.
- **Una derrota no da puntos**.

El número de partidos empatados es la resta del total de puntos con la cantidad de victorias multiplicadas por tres:

```
pempatados[i] = puntos[i] - pganados[i] * 3;
```

Y el número de partidos perdidos es la resta entre el total jugado con las victorias y empates, que ya tenemos.

```
pperdidos[i] = pjugados[i] - pganados[i] - pempatados[i]
```

También se puede hacer con una matriz, es bastante simple porque en esencia una matriz es como un conjunto de arreglos. Pero eso te lo dejo de tarea. ;)

Comment: Me gusta. Buena respuesta.